# WinUI framework and Microservices architecture

Tags: microservices, winui-3

I am planning to move a monolithic UWP application to a Microservices architecture. Based on my understanding, I will change all Domain/business logic into a microservices architecture. What about the `UI` Framework? Can I use WinUI-3 as the UI framework in this setup?  When I look in web, I see only web apps(angular, react.js, vue.js) using a microservices architecture. Can a `WinUI` App be used in a microservices architecture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can a WinUI App be used in a microservices arch?

Sure, what UI technology you choose to use should have nothing to do with how your backend is designed.

A WinUI app can certainly connect to a backend that is based on a microservice architecture.

Comment: So how will they communicate between ?

Comment: Like any other UI app would.